# Запустить ReactJS приложение локально

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Можно ли запустить скомпилированное приложение на reactjs в локальной папке, без запуска вебпак сервера?
Написал простенькое одностраничное приложение с помощью create-react-app, потом сбилбил его, и попытался запустить, чтобы оно работало как статический сайт, но оно не запускается, хотя пути к полученому js файлу все верные.

в том то и дело что ошибок нет, допустим беру вот такой боилерплейт, https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate - устанавливаю, компилирую, в полученной папке запускаю index.html, а на странице либо пусто, либо если в html файле поправить путь до скрипта показывается 404 страница, следовательно это все работает только если запустить сервер и положить туда все скомпилированные файлы, чтобы путь был от корня сайта

либо может посоветуете какой нибудь другой бойлерплейт где данная функция доступна? желательно чтобы там не было ничего лишнего, практически пустые странички с минимумом функционала и реализован роутинг

Comment: Можно. А чтобы разобраться, почему не запускается у вас, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, текст ошибки с которой не запускается ваше приложение.

Comment: поправил комментарий выше